# Error while dividing two columns value in a dataframe

Tags: pyldavis

I am receiving an error while dividing two columns value in a dataframe. This is the code:

```
df['lose%'] =  df['LostGames']/ df['PlayedGames']
```

This is my error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Can anyone help me with this ??

Answer (score 0):

df1.WonGames = pd.to_numeric(df1.WonGames)

df1.LostGames = pd.to_numeric(df1.LostGames)

df1.PlayedGames = pd.to_numeric(df1.PlayedGames)

---